# Sum of Geometric Progressions for any ordered Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits, field-theory, geometric-progressions

Given an Ordered Field $\left(F,+,\cdot, 1, 0, <\right)$ it can be easily shown that

$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a\cdot r^{n} = a\cdot\left(\frac{r^{n + 1} - 1}{r - 1}\right)$

What I'm interested is in if $|r| < 1$ does that still mean that if $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $r^{n} \rightarrow 0$ and as such

$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a\cdot r^{n} = \frac{a}{r - 1}$

We can certainly say that $|r^{n + 1} | < |r^{n}| < 1$

But for an ordered field can we say it goes to $0$ as it does with Real Numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The better analogy would be the rational numbers, not real numbers. Given a geometric series of rational numbers, with the quotient strictly between $-1$ and $1$, the limit exists in the completion of rational numbers, i.e. in the real numbers.

You could think that given a geometric series in an ordered field, with quotient between $-1$ and $1$, the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence in the field, so the limit exists *in the Dedekind completion* of the field, but that is not true, unfortunately.

For example, you can order ${\mathbf R}(X)$ so that $X$ is infinitesimal. Then the series $\sum_{n} 2^{-n}$ does not converge, because its partial sums are not a Cauchy sequence, but merely a pseudo-Cauchy sequence: the differences between consecutive elements get smaller and smaller, but not *arbitrarily small*: namely, the difference is never infinitesimal.

The correct condition in an ordered field would be to ask that the quotient $q$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to \infty} q^n=0$. Indeed, if $X$ is infinitesimal then the series $\sum_{n} X^n$ coverges in $\mathbf R((X))$, the completion of $\mathbf R(X)$. But if you take $Y$ to be infinitesimal with respect to $X$, then $\sum_{n} X^n$ will *not* converge in $\mathbf R((X,Y))$.

Note that there is nothing about this conclusion that is unique to ordered fields. In any topological field, if you have $q$ such that $q^n\to 0$ and any $a$, then $\sum aq^n$ converges for more or less the same reasons.

Finally, note that in general, if a field satisfies the property that every $q\in (-1,1)$ satisfies $q^n\to 0$, then it must be Archimedean. I don't remember the reasons, but as far as I recall, all Archimedean ordered fields are subfields of the reals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and it's detail.
Yes I'm sure it can be generalised further. I'm reading into an 'Intro to Abstract Algebra' textbook and was fascinated with Fields that many of the things I thought were exclusive to Real Numbers can be applied to all Fields. 

Yes I agree I should have used Rational Numbers with the limit being in the Reals.   

I apologise that there is a lot of your response that I can't respond to as I need to learn them but I will certainly return as my skill set/knowledge base grows. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @user3053801: Sure, you're welcome. :)

Comment: To the proposer: In an ordered field  there may exist $x,y$ with $0<x<y^n<1$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ and so the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$  cannot be said to be converging to $0.$.... In fact the set $\{y^n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ will not have a $glb,$ because if $0<x\leq x^*\leq y^n<1$ for all $n\in \Bbb N  $ then  $x^*\leq y^{n+1}$ for all $n\in \Bbb N,$  so $ x^*<x^*y^{-1}\leq y^n$  for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

Comment: Cheers @DanielWainfleet! 
Yes I wasn't sure if we need something like the extended real numbers with infinities in the set. 
Appreciate your comment.